# Sync EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, linux-networking, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I know many people have asked how to sync multiple ec2 instances and it seems the usual answer is to store all the assets in S3.  Would this still make sense if the only thing I am trying to share between instances are blank text files?

Let me give a little background as to what I am trying to accomplish.  Instead of having the user query the database to check for updated information every time, it compares the last modified date by touching a specific blank text file to a date stored on the device (iphone).  This allows it to only query the database when something has been updated.  My thinking was the less queries to the database the better.  Would the best way to do this still be to store these blank text files in S3 or is there a solution to sync these blank text files across multiple instances every 1-5 mins?

Comment: The **best** way in your case would be to use a proper database.

Comment: What do you mean a proper database?  Right now the EC2 instance has php scripts that make calls to RDS to grab a particular filename and then grabs that file from S3.  I want to limit the amount of unnecessary calls to RDS by comparing 2 last modified dates in a blank text file first but I need those text files to be synced across multiple Ec2 instances

Comment: You don't need S3 at all here. Just store the timestamp directly in the database and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If you are attempting to prevent DB access and can live with non-persistent storage, why not use a cache.

Memcache could fill the bill, is fast, and is simple to setup and program for.  Redis and several others can do much the same while providing some persistence.